# using token based authentication for HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, authentication, html5-video

I'm currently using JWT for each route that needs authentication on my web app, using passport on a NodeJS server. The token is stored by the front-end and every request made is used with an axios instance with the header "Authorization" set to the token.

Everything works fine with that, but now I want to use show videos an user has uploaded. To do that, I want to use the same mechanism. The issue is that using the `<video>`  HTML tag, the only thing to get the ressource is using the `src` attribute, but I can't figure a way to make make it use the 'Authorization' header as it's not using axios.

Is there a way to do that or am I forced to implement myself some sort of player using the Media Source API ? I tried also putting the token as a query string in the URL. It does work but is that safe to do so as the auth token (or a new one for the video ressource only) will be shown?

Note: (I'm able to download the whole file with axios and then put a blob as a src, but it's really inefficient)

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find any player that supports this. All players fallback to use browser when playing media files with `<video>` and there is not way to fiddle with Headers to set Authentication token.

The only way to add headers is when you use protocols like HLS. Then the request are made via XHR and you can access request headers:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <video
         id="my_video"
         class="video-js"
         controls
         preload="auto"
         width="640"
         height="268"
         data-setup="{}"
         >
  </video>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.js"></script>
  <script>
  videojs.Hls.xhr.beforeRequest = function(options) {
    options.headers = options.headers || {};
    options.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer token';
    console.log('options', options)
    return options;
  };
  var player = videojs('my_video');
  player.ready(function() {
    this.src({
       src: "https://dl5.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm",
      type: "video/webm",
    });
  });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am running the code snippet and I can't see any authorization header in the network. where have you seen the authorization header?

Comment: It is working only for streaming video, from m3u8 playlist

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I approached a similar situation:

1. make a handshake endpoint that tells your server that you are going to request a video, this endpoint is protected by authentication, what this endpoint does is to return a uuid that represents the video that is about to be requested.
2. the video streaming endpoint only accepts the uuid that was returned from the handshake.

BTW, I maintain a session Map that record each user and their corresponding tokens, so if I found out a session is outdated (like idle for 30 minutes) and removed, then all the uuids generated for that session are also all removed, so no one can access them even if they somehow got the uuids.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The issue of doing so, is that there is no authentication for getting the ressource server side. This mean that any one that have the links (during the lifetime of your session) still can access the ressource.
Anyway, what I wanted is having a stateless authentication mechanism, because I don't want to handle session. This question is specific for tokens only authentication mechanisms, because if I have sessions, the authorization cookie session should be sent when the <video> tags load the video.

Comment: OMG yeah this is really a terrible idea. It's called "security through obscurity". HTTP URLs are logged in A LOT of places. You'd also have to make sure the code for computing the session age is bullet proof. Plus this functionality already exists in a more secure form - it's called a session cookie. Why not just use that?